# Boxplots with overlapping distribution/histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Kind of in short: I am basically trying to draw a boxplot based on a continuos varible, where each box represents the entries inside a certain range of this variable. And on top of that I want to superimpose a histogram to show the distribution (how many counts are there in each interval).

A bit more explained: I have a dataframe with various columns. I am interested in grouping them by intervals on a certain continuous column X and drawing a boxplot of how column Y looks for each interval of column X. In addition, I would like to superimpose a distribution or historgam to show how many elements are on each boxplot, more or less.

I have tried (and failed) plotting the histogram with the addecuate bins. Then classifying the data according to the middle value of each bin so that I can plot both (histogram and boxplot) on the same axes or using the same x-axis (`axes.twinx()`) but then the histogram deforms. Its like it is not recognizing the values for the x-axis as the same.

Original histogram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHdOW.jpg

After trying to add the boxplots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPPUU.jpg

Here is an illustrative example of what I have been trying to do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


# Generate random data
prices = np.random.uniform(low=-85.0,high=85.0, size=(50,))
value_x = np.random.uniform(low=0,high=3000.0, size=(50,))
df = pd.DataFrame({'price':prices,'value_x':value_x })
# Classify each entry according to the bin they belong to
df['interval_index'] = np.digitize(df['price'], np.arange(-85,85,5))
# Get middle value for each bin, for example, if bin is (40-45), middle value would be 42.5
df['interval_middle_value'] = df['interval_index']*5-87.5

# Failed attempt to generate the desired plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.distplot(df['price'],bins=np.arange(-85,85,5), ax=ax, kde=False, norm_hist=False)
ax2=ax.twinx()
sns.boxplot(x='interval_middle_value',y='value_x',data=df, ax=ax2)
```

I would expect an outcome like the following graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZEfc.jpg

Comment: Your code and graphs don't match up - the code says you're using a uniform distribution but the graph looks pretty normal to me?

Comment: that's because the code I posted here is just an example generated with random data, so it is not the real data that I am using. That's why they look different, but aside from the data generation (basically, after the second comment), I am doing exactly the same things that are shown in the code that I posted.

Comment: You should really make sure your examples are consistent so we know exactly what you're expecting (particularly, if you can seed your random). Anyway, your issue is that the boxplot is a categorical plot, and so what you think are x values consistent with your histogram are not. Do the two on separate sets of axes and `print(ax.get_xlim())` for each to see what I mean

Comment: Okay, sorry about that, I will keep it in mind for the next time I post a question. So, taking into account this categorical vs continuous plot issue, is there a way to plot both together so that they look similar to the expected outcome I mentioned in the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the boxplot is categorical, you need to set the positions of the boxes to the middle of the bin intervals.
Hence, probably you are looking for something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate random data
prices = np.random.uniform(low=-85.0,high=85.0, size=(500,))
value_x = np.random.uniform(low=0,high=3000.0, size=(500,))
df = pd.DataFrame({'price':prices,'value_x':value_x })
# Classify each entry according to the bin they belong to
bins = np.arange(-85,90,5)

width = np.diff(bins)[0]
df['interval_index'] = np.digitize(df['price'], bins)
# Get middle value for each bin, for example, if bin is (40-45), middle value would be 42.5
middle_value = bins[:-1] + width/2

# Failed attempt to generate the desired plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(df['price'].values, bins=bins)
ax2=ax.twinx()

stats = [df['value_x'][df['interval_index'] == i].values for i in range(1, len(bins))]
ax2.boxplot(stats, positions=middle_value, widths=width*0.6, manage_ticks=False)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This really solves the issue about the categoricalx-axis from boxplots.

Comment: I appreciate that boxplpts are derigeur in certain fields, but I think this would be better represented as a series of lines versus x at each confidence interval, perhaps with line thickness changing to show the different intervals.